# PlantUML different layouts

Tags: plantuml

I am using PlantUML API to generate Activity Diagram.

I have used GraphViz before and used rank parameter to define layout

```
rank=LR [for left to right]
```

I am trying to find similiar thing in PlantUML where I can change its orientation to "Left to Right" instead of existing layout i.e. "Top to Bottom".

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can use the following command with State, Class, Component or Usecase diagrams:

```
left to right direction
```

(see https://plantuml.com/use-case-diagram#d551e48d272b2b07)

**Edit:** This comment from 2012 originally claimed that the feature was scheduled for *the next release*. It's been available forever now.

Comment: This is implemented as beta feature in version 7929.

Comment: I have 3 namespaces in the UML.
The image that gets generated is too **wide**.
I tried to use
    _top to bottom direction_
but that hasn't had any effect

Comment: @MMM Same for me. Interestingly, if I use `left to right`, I get a narrower diagram.

Comment: Using `left to right direction` also seems to transpose the direction of the arrows in a Class Diagram – if you have arrows pointing `-up->`, they will be rendered pointing left, but arrows pointing `-left->` will render pointing up.