# How to make a plant uml activity diagram travel left to right

Tags: plantuml

I've created an activity diagram with swimlanes in plant uml the diagram travels from top to bottom but I want to make it travel left to right. I found this answer about [PlantUML different layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581848/plantuml-different-layouts) but it does not seem to apply to activity diagrams. And when i tried to apply "left to right direction" to my diagrams there were errors.

Example code

```
@startuml
|Swimlane 1|
start
 :Do something;
|Swimlane 2|
 :Do something;
 stop
@enduml
```

Diagram that I want to travel from left to right instead of top to bottom.

[image]

Comment: This question has been open for a while now, and PlantUML has not implemented nor announced this feature as of yet. Have you considered accepting an answer?

Answer (score 11):

There is no way to do this in PlantUML.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, PlantUML does not support this.

If you want this feature to be implemented, let the author(s) of PlantUML know by upvoting this feature request:

http://www.forum.plantuml.net/13375/supports-horizontal-swimlane-diagrams